# Replace first character of sting in PHP with rules

Tags: php, string

I'm wanting to replace the first character of a string with a specific character depending on its value,

```
A = 0
B = 1
C = 2
```

Is there a way to do this based on rules? In total I will have 8 rules.

Ok, so I'm editing this to add more information as I don't think some people understand / want to help without the full picture...

My string will be any length between 5 and 10 characters
Capitals will not factor into this, it is not case sensitive
Currently there is no code, I'm not sure the best way to do this. I can write an if statement on a substring, but I know straight away that is inefficient.

Below is the before and after that I am expecting, I have kept these examples simple but all I am looking to do is replace the first character with a specific character depending on its value. For now, there are eight rules, but this could grow in the future

```
INPUT          OUTPUT
ANDREW         1NDREW
BRIAN          2RIAN
BOBBY          2OBBY
CRAIG          3RAIG
DAVID          4AVID
DUNCAN         4UNCAN
EDDIE          5DDIE
FRANK          6RANK
GEOFF          7EOFF
GIANA          7IANA
HAYLEY         8AYLEY
```

So as you can see, pretty straight forward, but is there a simple way to specifically specify what a character should be replaced by?

Comment: Share all the rules and your code.

Comment: What if the letters are not capitalized, should they still be replaced?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming all the rules are for single characters, like in the example, it would be easisest to code them in to a dictionary:

```
$rules = array('A' => 0, 'B' => 0 /* etc... */);
$str[0] = $rules[$str[0]];
```

Comment: This actually worked for me, I just needed to concatenate the remainder of the string to the end of it.

Comment: That should be an in-place transform, no append needed.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want.

```
<?php

$input = array('ANDREW','BRIAN','BOBBY','CRAIG','DAVID','DUNCAN','EDDIE','FRANK','GEOFF','GIANA','HAYLEY');
$array = range('A','Z');
$array = array_flip(array_filter(array_merge(array(0), $array)));
$output = [];

foreach($input as $k=>$v){
    $output[] = $array[$v[0]].substr($v, 1);
}

print_r($output);
?>
```

**Output:**

```
Array ( 
 [0] => 1NDREW
 [1] => 2RIAN 
 [2] => 2OBBY 
 [3] => 3RAIG
 [4] => 4AVID
 [5] => 4UNCAN
 [6] => 5DDIE
 [7] => 6RANK
 [8] => 7EOFF
 [9] => 7IANA 
 [10] => 8AYLEY
)
```

**DEMO:** https://3v4l.org/BHLPk